# Why echo of combined variables in for loop doesn't work?

Tags: bash, for-loop, variables, input, echo

what is wrong with "echo" line in my loop? 
It should echo value of v1 after 1st input, v2 after 2nd input and v3 after 3rd input. Instead it's just echoes $i. Why is it ignoring $v ?
After loop is done, I do "manual check" of the saver variables and they apparently exist.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..3}
 do
  read -p "Insert value $i: " v$i
  echo "you wrote " $v$i          #I have problem in this line
 done

echo
echo "check of saved values:"
echo $v1
echo $v2
echo $v3
```

Console output:

```
./input_2.sh
Insert value 1: what
you wrote  1              #output should be: you wrote what
Insert value 2: the
you wrote  2              #output should be: you wrote the
Insert value 3: hell
you wrote  3              #output should be: you wrote hell

check of saved values:
what
the
hell
```

Thanks

Comment: Assuming that `i` is 1: You indeed read into a variable named `v1`, and the user's response is stored into this variable.but you never expand this variable (for this you would have to write `$v1`). Instead you wrote `$v$i`, which means the expansion of the variable `v` catenated to the expansion of the variable `i`. Since you never assigned anything to `v`, `$v` expands to the null string, and `$i` expands to `1`. Hence your echo shows `1`.

Answer (score 3):

This line:

`echo "you wrote " $v$i`

Tries to write variable `$v` followed by `$i`.

What you need is to store the variable name into a variable and then use the `${!}`, for example:

```sh
varname=v$i
echo "you wrote " ${!varname}
```

A good practice would be to use this variable name for the `read` operation as well:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..3}
 do
  varname=v$i
  read -p "Insert value $i: " $varname
  echo "you wrote " ${!varname}
 done

echo
echo "check of saved values:"
echo $v1
echo $v2
echo $v3
```

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out, you need indirect variable expansion. However, you can also use an array to group related values. `v[$i]` is a valid name for `read`.

```
for i in {1..3}
 do
  read -p "Insert value $i: " "v[$i]"
  echo "you wrote ${v[$i]}"
 done

echo
echo "check of saved values:"
echo "${v[1]}"
echo "${v[2]}"
echo "${v[3]}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Also works with `printf`

```
for i in {1..3}; {
    varname=v$i
    read -p "Insert value $i: " value 
    printf -v $varname "$value"
    echo  "you wrote $value"
}

echo
echo "check of saved values:"
echo $v1
echo $v2
echo $v3
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. Just use an array and populate it inside the loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

values=()
for i in {1..3}; do
  read -p "Insert value $i: " v
  values+=("$v")
  printf '%s %s\n' "you wrote" "$v"
done

echo
echo "check of saved values:"
echo ${values[0]}
echo ${values[1]}
echo ${values[2]}
```

Just keep in mind that bash arrays are starts from zero `0` index.

---

EDIT: As pointed out by Ivan, the zero indexed array can be change according to the value of the for loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
values=()
for i in {1..3}; do
  read -p "Insert value $i: " v
  values[$i]="$v"
  printf '%s %s\n' "you wrote" "$v"
done

echo
echo "check of saved values:"
echo ${values[1]}
echo ${values[2]}
echo ${values[3]}
```

Comment: But you can add any index `values[$i]="$v"` and then `echo ${values[1]}; echo ${values[2]}; echo ${values[3]}`

Comment: @Ivan Updated the answer. Much obliged.